# Align all childs elements inside a div in a Table cell

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to align all child elements inside a div which is a child of table cell.
This is my Code:

```
<td>
     <div class="tablechild">310.2
          <span class="subitem">01:10 PM</span>
     </div>
</td>
```

Comment: How do you want the contents to be aligned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
<td style="text-align:right">
    <div class="tablechild">310.2<br/>
       <span class="subitem">01:10 PM</span>
    </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.tablechild {
    position: relative;
}
.tablechild .subitem {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    right: 0;
    width: 80px;
    text-align: right;
}
```